# My job application is not showing anywhere

Tags: support, jobs

I applied to a position in StackExchange careers some months ago, and it didn't go anywhere. There were apparently some problems with the process, and it was reopened recently (last week). An email was sent to the previous applicants stating that the application *must* be resubmitted (presumably using the same link as last time). I send my application again, and I received this message

```
You have previously applied for this position. A new application has not been submitted.
```

Yet when I check my sent applications in the messages tab, there is nothing.

Comment: The message is quite clear, you can't apply to same position more than once. Not sure what you think the bug is.

Comment: I guess I need to be clearer in the main body. This is the same job opening that was available months ago, and an email was sent to those who applied that clearly stated that the application has to be resubmitted (presumably using the same link). I resubmit, as stated in the email, and I got the message that I posted.

Comment: The company really shouldn't have done that. Can you contact careers@stackoverflow.com so we can investigate further?